# Dagger2 Using an entire Dependency Graph

Tags: dagger-2

I have set up dagger2 dependencies in my app as I understand it and through the many examples.  What I have not found is the proper way to use all of the dependencies once they are injected.

Each of the singletons in the module depends on the output of the singleton before it.  How is the entire dependency graph used without calling each singleton in turn to get the required inputs?

Given the following:

AppComponent

```
@Singleton
@Component(modules = {
        DownloaderModule.class
})
public interface AppComponent {
    void inject(MyGameActivity activity);
}
```

DownloaderModule

```
@Module
public class DownloaderModule {

    public static final String NETWORK_CACHE = "game_cache";

    private static final int GLOBAL_TIMEOUT = 30; // seconds

    public DownloaderModule(@NonNull String endpoint) {
        this(HttpUrl.parse(endpoint));
    }

    @Provides @NonNull @Singleton
    public HttpUrl getEndpoint() {
        return this.endpoint;
    }

    @Provides @NonNull @Singleton @Named(NETWORK_CACHE)
    public File getCacheDirectory(@NonNull Context context) {
        return context.getDir(NETWORK_CACHE, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    }

    @Provides @NonNull @Singleton
    public Cache getNetworkCache(@NonNull @Named(NETWORK_CACHE) File cacheDir) {
        int cacheSize = 20 * 1024 * 1024; // 20 MiB
        return new Cache(cacheDir, cacheSize);
    }

    @Provides @NonNull @Singleton
    public OkHttpClient getHttpClient(@NonNull Cache cache) {
        return new OkHttpClient.Builder()
                .cache(cache)
                .connectTimeout(GLOBAL_TIMEOUT, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                .readTimeout(GLOBAL_TIMEOUT, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                .writeTimeout(GLOBAL_TIMEOUT, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                .build();
    }
```

MyGameApp

```
public class MyGameApp extends Application {

    private AppComponent component;

    private static Context context;

    public static MyGameApp get(@NonNull Context context) {
        return (MyGameApp) context.getApplicationContext();
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        component = buildComponent();
        MyGameApp.context = getApplicationContext();

      }

    public AppComponent component() {
        return component;
    }

    protected AppComponent buildComponent() {
        return DaggerAppComponent.builder()
                .downloaderModule(new DownloaderModule("https://bogus.com/"))
                .build();
    }

}
```

Comment: How do you mean, "depends on the output of the singleton before it"? It looks like your Module is well-structured to inject each piece it needs, by taking each piece as an input parameter in the corresponding `@Provides` method. You should be able to inject `OkHttpClient` or any of the other dependencies you've created from within your MyGameActivity.

Comment: I am simply having trouble getting its straight in my head.  I read some more and the concepts are sinking in.  What is frustrating is there are tons of articles showing how to set it up, but  actual use examples are hard to find. I am working with a decent example now.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll try to shed some light into this, but there are several ways you can read this. I prefer a bottom up approach - Basically start on what your objects require and work my way up. In this case, I would start at `MyGameActivity`. Unfortunately, you didn't paste the code for this, so I'll have to be a bit creative, but that's ok for the purpose of the exercise.

So in your app you're probably getting the `AppComponent` and calling `inject` for your `MyGameActivity`. So I guess this activity has some injectable fields. I'm not sure if you're using there directly `OkHttpClient` but let's say you do. Something like:

```
public class MyGameActivity extends SomeActivity {
   @Inject
   OkHttpClient okHttpClient;
   // ...
}
```

The way I like to think about this is as follows. Dagger knows you need an `OkHttpClient` given by the `AppComponent`. So it will look into how this can be provided - Can it build the object itself because you annotated the constructor with `@Inject`? Does it require more dependencies?.

In this case it will look into the modules of the component where this client is being provided. It will reach `getHttpClient` and realise it needs a `Cache` object. It will again look for how this object can be provided - Constructor injection, another provider method?.

It's again provided in the module, so it will reach `getNetworkCache` and once more realise it needs yet another dependency.

This behaviour will carry on, until it reaches objects that require no other dependencies, such as your `HttpUrl` in `getEndpoint`.

After all this is done, your `OkHttpClient` can be created.

I think it's easy to understand from this why you can't have cycles in your dependency graph - You cannot create an object `A` if it depends on `B` and `B` depends on `A`. So imagine that for some weird reason you'd reach the method `getEndpoint` which would depend on the `OkHttpClient` from that module. This wouldn't work. You'd be going in circles an never reach an end.

So if I understand your question: *How is the entire dependency graph used without calling each singleton in turn to get the required inputs?*

It's not. It has to call all the methods to be able to get the singletons. At least the first time they're provided within the same component/scope. After that, as long as you keep the same instance of your component, the scoped dependencies will always return the same instance. Dagger will make sure of this. If you'd for some reason destroy the component or recreate it, then the dependencies wouldn't be the same instances. More info [here](https://google.github.io/dagger/users-guide.html#singletons-and-scoped-bindings). In fact this is true for all scopes. Not just `@Singleton`s.

However, as far as I can tell you're doing it right. When your application is created you create the component and cache it. After that, every time you use the method `component()` you return always the same component and the scoped dependencies are always the same.

Comment: I did figure it out and am using it.  As I do dependency injection in Spring, it was difficult to change my thought process and the need to set it up myself by implementation.  That Dagger would do so much with just a single call is really cool.  I gave you an upvote for the complete answer.